# rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raspberry-pi3

On my Pi, I have Rails 6.0.3.1 installed but when I cd into my project folder and check the rails version I get the following:

```
Deprecation warning: Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean).
This will be rejected in the future unless you explicitly pass the options `check_default_type: false` or call `allow_incompatible_default_type!` in your code
You can silence deprecations warning by setting the environment variable THOR_SILENCE_DEPRECATION.
Rails 4.2.4
```

I honestly dont know what that means because i'm just a pure beginner.
I made few researches and found that I could upgrade the rails 4.2.4 with `rake rails:update` but when i run it gives the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:85:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:80:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails.rb:11:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `'
/home/pi/tritoneye/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/pi/tritoneye/config/application.rb:3:in `'
/home/pi/tritoneye/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/pi/tritoneye/Rakefile:4:in `'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do i solve this? 
Please help.Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the version of rails on your path is 4.2.4.  `rake rails:update` is an task that helps you update existing rails apps - it does not change you path setup at all. What is that you are doing here? Are you looking to work on an existing rails 4.2.4 app or create a new rails app with 6.0.3.1?

Comment: Why do you decide to update rails? It's not as easy as it looks

Comment: I decide to update rails in hope that it will help solve some others issue i found when running here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150171/undefined-method-new-for-bigdecimalclass-nomethoderror)

Comment: When updating Rails, go to the next "dot" version, in this case 5.0.7.2.  Going from 4 -> 6; that's not noob territory.